# how to separate data in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm preparing a set of data to be graphed on google api, the data needs to be formatted this way.

ie.

1,2,3|1,2,3|1,2,3

now, my output keeps coming out as:

1,2,3|1,2,3|1,2,3|

I'm trying to remove the last separator or not have it there at all here's an example of what my code may look like:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc//names[text()=$name]/..//loc">
        <xsl:value-of select="100- . +1"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())" >
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()= last() " >
            <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

OR

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc//names[text()=$name]/..//loc">
        <xsl:value-of select="100- . +1"/>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(position() = last())" >,</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>|</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

is there a way to concat or strip , split , or maybe mod, . join, tokenize?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a string-join function. Never had to use it though myself.

Comment: Is that really a representative sample of your XSLT? Are you sure you don't have another **xsl:for-each** containing your current code? Or maybe it is in a template match that would be get called multiple times? Maybe showing a bit more XSLT would help? Thanks!

Comment: What version of xslt?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the XSLT snippet you have shown us, I would only expect it to output the `|` character once, and not multiple times you have shown us.

It might be your code sample is in another **xsl:for-each** or maybe within an **xsl:template match="..."**, for example, and so is getting called multiple times.

In this case, perhaps you just need to move the output of the pipe character outside of the inner loop you have shown

```
<xsl:for-each select="$doc//names[text()=$name]/..//loc">
    <xsl:value-of select="100- . +1"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())" >
        <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:if test="position()= last() " >
    <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

(As an aside, I have no idea what `<xsl:value-of select="100- . +1"/>` is meant to be doing, as it should just output 'NaN')

A different, is more crude solution, would be to put your current code inside a variable, and then just output the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="data">
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc//names[text()=$name]/..//loc">
        <!-- Existing code -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($data, 1, string-length($data) - 1" />
```